# C# POCO class for Mongo sample database

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am trying to write a Model for the 'movie' collection in the 'sample_mflix' database that is part of the "sample" databases available for MongoDB (https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/sample-data/available-sample-datasets/). Here is what I have so far:

```
namespace BSoftSolutions.Models
{
  [BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
  public class TomatoViewer
  {
      public float rating;
      public int numReviews;
      public int meter;
  }
  [BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
  public class Tomato
  {
      public TomatoViewer viewer;
      public string production;
      public long lastUpdated;
  }
  [BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
  public class Award
  {
      public int wins;
      public int nominations;
      public string text;
  }
  [BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
  public class Imdb
  {
      public float rating;
      public int votes;
      public int id;
  }
  [BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
  public class Movie
  {
      public string plot;
      public IEnumerable<string> genres;
      public int runtime;
      public IEnumerable<string> cast;
      public string title;
      public string fullplot;
      public IEnumerable<string> languages;
      public long released;
      public IEnumerable<string> directors;
      public IEnumerable<string> writers;
      public Award awards;
      public string lastupdated;
      public int year;
      public Imdb imdb;
      public IEnumerable<string> countries;
      public string type;
      public Tomato tomatoes;
  }
}
```

When I do a query like

```
results = MongoCollection.AsQueryable<Movie>().Select(x => x.title).ToList();
```

I get a exception thrown with a message that the serializer cannot create a string from the BsonType Int32.

```
{System.FormatException: Cannot deserialize a 'String' from BsonType 'Int32'.    at . . . .
```

I have looked over my model a number of times and cannot see where the database has an int32 and my model says it is a string. I have gone so far as removing all the fields in the class  but one and I still get the same serialization exception. Can someone point out some obvious flaw in the model class that I am missing? Or educate me on how to find out which field is causing the problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem was not the type definitions, tho I changed some types there

- tomato -> lastUpdated is a `DateTime`
- Imdb -> rating is a `decimal`
- Movie -> released is a `DateTime`

So the problem was that the "title" were not always a `string` (my guess when the title is just a number. Like spartan 300). There were 36 rows, where the "title" was `int` really. To overcome this, I changed the type to `dynamic` and check if there were `int`s really.

```
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class TomatoViewer
{
    public float rating;
    public int numReviews;
    public int meter;
}
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class Tomato
{
    public TomatoViewer viewer;
    public string production;
    public DateTime lastUpdated;
}
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class Award
{
    public int wins;
    public int nominations;
    public string text;
}
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class Imdb
{
    public decimal rating;
    public int votes;
    public int id;
}
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class Movie
{
    public string plot;
    public IEnumerable<string> genres;
    public int runtime;
    public IEnumerable<string> cast;
    public dynamic title;
    public string fullplot;
    public IEnumerable<string> languages;
    public DateTime released;
    public IEnumerable<string> directors;
    public IEnumerable<string> writers;
    public Award awards;
    public string lastupdated;
    public int year;
    public Imdb imdb;
    public IEnumerable<string> countries;
    public string type;
    public Tomato tomatoes;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{

    var client =
        new MongoClient(
            "mongodb+srv://...");
    var database = client.GetDatabase("sample_mflix");
    var movies = database.GetCollection<Movie>("movies");
    var titles = movies.AsQueryable().Select(x => x.title).ToList();
    foreach (var numTitle in titles.OfType<int>())
    {
        Console.Write(numTitle);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I have asked the Mongo team, if they can make all titles string. If you download the sample database freshly, they are all strings now.

Comment: Thank you. This goes a long way to solving my beginners question. Two follow-on questions. What tools did you use to discover the type changes that were needed? How did you zero in on these type changes? The second question seems to deal with the 'dynamic' type. When I make the one property dynamic it seems to make the whole class dynamic (which makes sense). But a query like 'var results = MongoCollection.AsQueryable<Movie>().Select(x => x.title).ToList();' Where I would want the results to be a list of string not List<dynamic>.  How can I convert the int's to strings?

Comment: I guessed, that if you write `x.title` it would not try to select all of the properties (if you already express queries in mongodb by property names, why would you loose the expressiveness by querying all the properties). Also `movies.AsQueryable().Select(x => x.title).Take(10)` worked for the first time with string, and the mentioned type changes.

Comment: the mentioned type changes were straight forward guesses. Wanted a DateTime instead of string > which property looks like a date... `release` and `lastUpdated`. Than an exception came, that I loose precision. Guessed for the float, and bingo.

Comment: when you want all the titles as strings, first query them all as dynamic, than enumerate through the titles (with `ToList`), so it's in memory. Only after that you can call ToString on all of them> `var titles = movies.AsQueryable().Select(x => x.title).ToList().Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList();`

Comment: This kind of database is using that each row could have other "class" to deserialize into. That's how mongodb was designed. That's a sample database tho. I would restrict myself to same named property should always have same type. Or handle it like JSON's `JToken`/`JObject`/... and go full dynamic. Use `BsonDocument` or `dynamic` everywhere.

Comment: Then maybe it is a bug. The query 'var results = MongoCollection.AsQueryable<Movie>().Select(x => x.title).ToList().Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList();'  still shows the results as a 'List<dynamic>'.

Comment: Hmm. I was hasty... `var results = MongoCollection.AsQueryable<Movie>().Select(x => x.title).ToList().Select(x => x.ToString()).Cast<string>().ToList();`

Comment: If you go to https://cloud.mongodb.com and browse the collection and start to update a field you can have a hint on what are the types of the properties.